# Getting a lot of x44 temp tasks in my Linux Server

Tags: apache-http-server, cpu-usage

There are a lot of tasks as shown in the below image,

[image]

Not sure, how and what to do. Due to this there is a 90+% of CPU consumption in htop

Anyone can help me out?

I am using Apache Server with Lararvel Application,
bought it from Digital Ocean

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What you’re seeing are threads. It may be helpful to disable userland thread display in _htop_ because there are so many of them. I suggest also using _t_ (tree view), maybe you can figure out what launched the process.

Answer (score 0):

It's malware. Probably a 'miner'. The `tsm` file looks like a regular copy of ld-linux.so, while `tsm64` is the actual process binary, and `httpd` is just a fake name to be put in argv[0]. (Note that all those tasks belong to one process (56274); the rest are threads within that process. Press Shift+H to show or hide threads.)

As part of malware removal, you should investigate *how* it got there in the first place, i.e. don't rush to kill or delete everything. I'd temporarily pause the process with `kill -STOP` or lower its priority with `renice` (as killing it may just have it auto-restart sometime later).

1. Note that the process is running under *your own* account, not under 'httpd' or 'www-data' or anything like that, which means it's your personal SSH account that was breached. **It's time to change your SSH password** and create a new SSH keypair.
2. Look inside the `/tmp/.X44-unix/.rsync/c/lib/64` directory, paying attention to the 'inode change' and 'modification' times of the files, as well as their owner username. (Try `ls -lac` or `stat <path>` for the 'inode change' time.)
3. Check your system logs (auth.log, security.log, journalctl) to see if there have been any logins around that time, from unusual IP addresses, to confirm if it was actually done via SSH.
4. Check `/proc/56274/cgroup` to see if the process belong to any specific systemd unit. If it belongs to a user .slice, it was started either manually or via cron (most likely); if it belongs to a .service, it was started by that service (unlikely).
5. Check your personal crontab and the system crontab for unusual jobs that would start the process. Remove them (using `crontab -e` for personal cron).

   ```
   sudo grep -r X44 /etc
   sudo grep -r X44 /var/spool/cron
   ```
6. Reboot to see if the process restarts; if it does, keep looking for locations that could be starting it.
7. Remove the entire `/tmp/.X44-unix` directory. (It's not an important directory; it's only meant to mimic the real /tmp/.X11-unix directory that holds Xorg sockets.)